# Trying to implement StickyListHeaders and SwipeMenuListView on the same ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to have a list view that has sticky headers as well as the ability to swipe left and have two options appear that are clickable.

I need both but the MAIN problem I am having is that StickyListHeaders requires me to declare my ListView like this

```
<se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And SwipeMenuListView requires me to declare my listViews like this

```
<com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Is there some sort of way to declare a listView as both a SwipeMenuListView and a StickyListHeaders ListView in the xml?

Or is there any sort of workaround for this?

Please bear with me as this is my first ever post on stack overflow.

Also, here are links to the two github projects I want to include in my project.

[StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)

[SwipeMenuListView](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView)